# How to call method on suds in python?

Tags: python, api, vmware, suds, vsphere

Particularly, I'm working with python and vmware vsphere to make virtual machine creation/power on and stuff like that automated. I know how to print attributes of virtual machines, however, I still can't call any methods because I don't know how.

this is code snippet I'm having trouble with:

```
for vm in virtual_machines:
print "VM: "+vm['name']+"  ("+vm['runtime.powerState']+") ",
if hasattr(vm['guest'],'ipAddress'):
    print vm['guest'].ipAddress,
if vm['runtime.powerState'] == 'poweredOn':
    print 'RAM: '+str(vm['summary.quickStats'].distributedMemoryEntitlement)+'MB, CPU: '+str(vm['summary.quickStats'].distributedCpuEntitlement)+'MHz',
if vm['name'] == 'VIRT_VZ_114':
    # This is the trouble maker, it says types mismatch "suds.TypeNotFound: Type not found: 'guest'"
    client.service.PowerOnVM_Task(mo_VirtualMachine,vm)
print
```

How do I call methods correctly?

Comment: What type of objects is `mo_VirtualMachine`? What is the WSDL signature of `PowerOnMVM_Task`?

Comment: Oh, mo_VirtualMachine I forgot to delete that, It was supposed to be an managed object referrence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at [psphere](https://github.com/jkinred/psphere) at all?

It's a python project to provide native bindings for the vSphere Web Services SDK.

You may be able to get your problems solved quicker with a dedicated library, rather than struggle with suds, SOAP and WDSL issues. It actually uses suds under the hood, but provides you with a pythonic API instead.